# Audacity: Assign left channel to both channels in mp3 file

Tags: macos, audio-recording, audacity, stereo

I'm using Audacity 1.3.12-beta on Mac OS X 10.6.7. In a band we recorded a couple of songs - in mono - and I converted them to mp3 files right away. And of course, I deleted the recordings immediately after converting. Problem is, now there's only sound in the left channel in the mp3's - how do I assign that to both channels?

Here's a picture to make things clearer:
[image]

Cheers!

**Edit:** before assigning the left track to both, I want to delete the right track, as it contains only noise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You essentially want to make a mono track.

Click on the Title drop down of the track ("Livin by the" in your screen shot) 
Choose Split Stereo to Mono. 
Delete the right track (Click the X in the upper right corner.) 
Export as necessary.

Done.